# Find anyone else who has taken leave on the selected date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find out who else has applied for the leave in given date range. I am trying like this (PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT
  hel.hrl_id,
  hry_type,
  hep.emp_id,
  hep.emp_code,
  hep.emp_firstname || ' ' || hep.emp_lastname AS NAME,
  hel.hrl_date_from,
  hel.hrl_date_to,
  hel.hrl_no_of_leave,
  hel.hrl_note,
  hel.hrl_applied_date,
  dep_name
FROM
  hr_emp_personal hep
LEFT JOIN hr_emp_official heo ON hep.emp_id = heo.emp_id
LEFT JOIN hr_emp_leave hel ON hep.emp_id = hel.emp_id
LEFT JOIN department_master dep ON heo.hro_department = dep.dep_id
LEFT JOIN hr_yearlyleavemaster hry ON hry.hry_id = hel.hry_id
WHERE
  hep.emp_left = 0
  AND hel.hrl_incharge_approve = 1
  AND hel.hrl_hr_approve = 1
  AND hel.hrl_date_to > CURRENT_DATE
  AND hrl_date_from <= '2015-10-23'
  AND hrl_date_to > '2015-10-26'
```

I have a record in database who taken leave from `24-10-2015` to `27-10-2015`. How can I do this? Employees need to know who else has taken leave in the given range.

Comment: The WHERE clause conditions for hel and other outer join tables make these LEFT JOINs to execute as regular inner joins. Move to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior.

Comment: Can't you edit the question instead of adding that major change as a comment?!?

Comment: @jar you should post your idea as an answer

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm not sure it's the answer. Perhaps it's just an improvement? (Maybe LEFT JOIN isn't needed at all...)

Comment: I got the answer. We can use overlap to find out any other record is coming in this date range.

select * from hr_emp_leave where (hrl_date_from, hrl_date_to) OVERLAPS ('2015-10-24','2015-10-25')